# PhpSpreadSheet to .txt

Tags: text-files, phpspreadsheet

I'm working in a web project to let people convert SpreaSheet file to formated text.

I was looking everywhere in [PHPSpreadSheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/) doc to find how to export a spreadsheet to a formated text file.

Do someone know how proceeding ?

Best regard

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? What are you struggling with, specifically? Please refer to [creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't help you unless you show us something first.

Comment: I haven't tried any thing, just want to know if phpspreadsheet can make export spreadsheet to formated text.

Comment: Might not be exactly what you have in mind, but you can write to the csv format. Look for the \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv section in the documentation [HERE](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/)